# Does KSQL supports insert array values?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

Want to insert values to a column having type of ARRAY . Didn't find any reference for this in KSQL reference guide. Please let me know if ksql has the support for this ? If yes how ?

Tried the following ways for `ARRAY<INTEGER>` but nothing works.

```
INSERT INTO SOMESTREAM(ARRAYVALUE[0],ARRAYVALUE[1],ARRAYVALUE[2]) VALUES(1,2,3);
INSERT INTO SOMESTREAM(ARRAYVALUE) VALUES({1,2,3});
INSERT INTO SOMESTREAM(ARRAYVALUE) VALUES([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: this is on our radar but there is not support for this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KSQL, as of version 5.3, does not yet support ARRAYs in INSERT VALUEs statements.  See Github issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3591.

Please stick a thumbs up on that issue or add a +1 comment to up-vote the issue.